# how to display timer on page load

Tags: javascript, timer

I think this should be simple, but I can't find anything online that I can make sense of. I would like to have a timer with minutes / seconds / milliseconds displayed on page load.

All I can find is timers with start stop buttons, the getMilliseconds method, which is more of a clock, etc...

Can someone please point me in the right direction here?

thanks!

Comment: What did you try? What are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you will want to take advantage of Javascript's onLoad function:

```
<body onLoad="startTimer()">
```

This, when the page is loaded, will call the startTimer() function located in your javascript. You could then use a setInterval set to 10 ms (the default minimum for most browsers). Then, you can update your HTML timer within the setInterval function.